# if $X$ has a finite number of isolated points, is $X$ compact?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

If every real valued continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous is $X$ is compact? 
Moreover if $X$ has a finite number of isolated points, is $X$ compact now?

I think that the answer to the first question is false  on considering $X=\mathbb N$. But I don't know how to go with  the second one? Any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $X$ is a metric space.  Suppose it is not compact.  Then there is a sequence $x_n$ that has no convergent subsequence.  Moreover, since $X$ has only finitely many isolated points, after removing a finite number of points we can assume none of the $x_n$ are isolated.  We may also assume the $x_n$ are distinct. 
For each $n$ there is $\epsilon_n$ such that $1/n > \epsilon_n > 0$ and 
$d(x_m, x_n) > \epsilon_n + \epsilon_m$ for all $m \ne n$.  Since $x_n$ is not isolated, we can assume there is $y_n \in X$ such that $\epsilon_n = d(x_n, y_n)$.
Consider the function
$f(x) = \sum_n f_n(x)$ where $f_n(x) = \max(0, 1 -  d(x, x_n)/\epsilon_n)$, and show that
this satisfies the conditions.

Comment: then how will i bring contradiction ....help to finish the proof

Comment: Sir, please could you describe a little more?

Comment: @Alearner What part don't you understand?

Comment: Always there would be only one $f_n$ non - zero (i.e. positive) ,as $n$ varying over the region. After that , what would be $f(x)$ , I couldn't get it , sir. $f(x)$ is bounded, but how could I show it is not uniformly continuous?

Comment: @Alearner Where is $f_n(x) = 1$?  Where is $f_n(x) = 0$?

Comment: $f(x)=1-\frac{d(x,x_n)}{\epsilon_n}$ , whenever $x \in B(x_{n},\epsilon) , \forall n $ and $f(x)=0 $ elsewhere , $f$ takes $1$ at each $x_n$. Sir, but here I can't understand the thing , how could it not be uniformly continuous on $X$?

Comment: So $f(x_n) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ at some point at distance $\epsilon_n$ from $x_n$.  How does that relate to the definition of uniformly continuous?

Comment: Sir, Taking $y_n= x_{n} + \frac{\epsilon_n}{2}$ ,$|x_{n} - y_n| \lt \frac{\epsilon_n}{2}$ , but $|f(x_n)- f(y_n)|\gt \frac{1}{4}$,, is this gonna work?

Comment: Thank you so much , sir.